# Customize ExtJs4 Mask

Tags: extjs, mask

I am using ExtJs mask while executing Ajax call.

```
var tmpMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), { msg: "Loading please wait..." });
tmpMask.show();
```

When request is finished I am hiding the mask

```
tmpMask.hide();
```

I would like to insert instead of text, div that includes image.

Please advice .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LoadMask `msg` is actually html, so you could put anything you want inside. 
I also recommend tring ExtJs templates techniques, like XTemplate for example.

Check it out:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

EDIT: example

http://jsfiddle.net/nW3Bv/1/

Comment: Could you give example how to put div instead of message ?